# Scala Type Variance for Implicit Conversion of Collection

Tags: java, scala

How come this doesn't work?

```
implicit class ImplicitHelper[T <: IndexedSeq[String]](i: T) = {
    def bar() = ???
}

val foo: Array[String] = ???
foo.bar // no implicit conversion …
```

doesn’t Array *implement?* IndexedSeq in the Scala unified collection hierarchy?

**Update:** As a few users pointed out, the dotted line represents not an implementation but a implicit conversion. thus the proper way is to use view bounds instead of type bounds per answers below

[image]

Comment: A bit confusing question. Maybe this helps: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non contiguous line represents a view, not a direct hierarchy:

```
final class Array[T](_length: Int) extends java.io.Serializable with java.lang.Cloneable
```

As you can see array doesn't extend `IndexedSeq`. Those views represent [implicit conversions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/collections)

[image]

So the only thing that means is that there's a conversion from `IndexedSeq` to `Array`.

Comment: thank you! that makes a lot of sense now ... @vitalii's answer using view bound works, powerful stuff!

Comment: You should maybe accept his answer since it actually solves the problem.

Comment: yup accepted moments ago, since it answers the question of 'why' my example didn't work. upvoted the other answer since it gave an good work around

Answer (score 1):

View bound works for me:

```
implicit class ImplicitHelper[T <% IndexedSeq[String]](i: T) {
    def bar() = ???
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, ill upvote the answer. this also works apparently: implicit class ImplicitHelper[T](i: T)(implicit ev$1: T => IndexedSeq[String])